# knowing if the left button of mouse is released on the same list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two list boxes, one for Avaiable Items and one for Selected items, so the user can move items between these two by either drag-drop or double-click.
It is not a perfect code and most of the logic is written in MouseMove event where I can have X and Y of the mouse location also...I am looking for this scenario to Prevent it: user holds left mouse button on the left list box and select an item BUT he releases the mouse button again on the same list box, so I need a way to know if it is still on the same list box then do not do the drag drop...so is there some method can tell me the boundaries of the list box that I can use? or any other better thoughts that you have?

```
private void lstAvailable_MouseMove(Object eventSender, MouseEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //*************** FUNCTION DETAILS ***************
    //User moves mouse in the Available list
    //***************** INSTRUCTIONS *****************
    MouseButtons Button = eventArgs.Button;
    int Shift = (int)Control.ModifierKeys / 0x10000;
    float X = (float)VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(eventArgs.X);
    float Y = (float)VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(eventArgs.Y);
    moDualListBox.List1_MouseMove(Button, Shift, X, Y);


    if (eventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
    {
        if (!mbClickProcessed) // it is a DragDrop
        {
            this.lstAvailable.DoDragDrop(this.lstAvailable.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
            mbClickProcessed = true;
        }
        if (mbClickProcessed) // it is a DoubleClick
        {
            MoveClick();
            MoveLostFocus();
            mbClickProcessed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample for drag-drop (no error checking):

```
private ListBox _DraggingListBox = null;

private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (_DraggingListBox != listBox1)
    MoveItem(listBox2, listBox1, (int)e.Data.GetData(typeof(int)));
}

private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  _DraggingListBox = listBox1;
  listBox1.DoDragDrop(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X,e.Y), DragDropEffects.Move);    
}

private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void listBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (_DraggingListBox != listBox2)
    MoveItem(listBox1, listBox2, (int)e.Data.GetData(typeof(int)));
}

private void listBox2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void listBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  _DraggingListBox = listBox2;
  listBox2.DoDragDrop(listBox2.IndexFromPoint(e.X,e.Y), DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void MoveItem(ListBox fromLB, ListBox toLB, int index)
{
  toLB.Items.Add(fromLB.Items[index]);
  fromLB.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Comment: did not work. I will put the MouseMove logic in my question soon, that logic is not good written good enough to work with this.

Comment: @BDotA DragDrop should start in the MouseDown event, not the MouseMove event.  You should probably handle the DoubleClick in the DoubleClick event, too.

Comment: yep I know. but it is a legacy code updated from VB 6.0 to C# and it is a reusable component used by other teams too, I am just looking for a quick and dirty way to fix it within the current code. Inside that logic I think if for drag-drop part I check the location of the where the mouse is and the boundaries of the listbox then I can determine of it is inside the same listbox so do not do the drag-drop yet.... so my question is how can I do that?

Comment: @BDotA: I don't understand why you're catching `MouseMove` event; if you **only** need to avoid drap-drop on same control, catch `DragDrop` event

Comment: did not work. I wrote your code, did not show the message box.

Comment: @BDotA I updated answer with working example (not checking for errors).

Comment: @BDotA: I think it didn't work because you use `this.lstAvailable.DoDragDrop` while you should use `lstAvailable.DoDragDrop`. With first syntax sender is form, not list!! Try...

Comment: @Marco: interesting, I tried it, did not work. now even in the DragDrop event I just wrote MessageBox.Show("dang!"), so no sender checking or anything and it is not event going there. weird... I think my last solution is to know if the mouse button is releases inside that list box or not...what is a good way to do that?

Comment: @BDotA: catching `MouseUp` event and checking _sender_ object.

Comment: @BDotA sender wasn't working for me either (saw it on MSDN) when I tested it, so I changed it to setting a variable in the MouseDown event.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch `DragDrop` event you have th sender of drag-drop operation.
So you can easily discard the operation (or do nothing) if sender is same as destination control...

If you want to know if mouse is leaving a control (and set a variable according to this) you can catch `MouseLeave` event, while `MouseEnter` event is handy to know when mouse enters a control from another one.

Comment: did not work. I will put the MouseMove logic in my question soon, that logic is not good written good enough to work with this.

Comment: Can we see the code you used to try my solution (and @LarsTech one, is the same described here)? It souns really strange that doesn't work...